# How to use group by on 2 different columns and use SUM function in mysql

Tags: php, mysql, group-by, aggregate-functions

I have this table:

[image]

and I want records like this:

```
Leave_detail_id   emp_id  leave_count
-------------------------------------
  1                 22       3
  3                 22       2
  2                 30       4
```

Please help me how to use multiple `GROUP BY` with `SUM`

Comment: The two first lines are making no sens. This is so weird to have the same emp_id twice with a different leave_count. It confused me when I started writing an answer. I am not the one who downvoted you. The data is not related with the question, it only making it confusing.

Comment: I can't understand what you are trying to achieve. Why Leave_detail_id=1 with emp_id = 32 was discarded?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT leave_detail_id, emp_id, SUM(leave_count) FROM table GROUP BY Leave_detail_id, emp_id;
```

Answer (score -1):

I think they want the fields in the select as well,

```
SELECT leave_detail_id, emp_id, SUM(leave_count) FROM table GROUP BY leave_detail_id, emp_id;
```